# Next/Image's components are too slow to appear

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm using Next.js 10.0.7 and next-images 1.7 and big images take some seconds to appear.

I'm using the components correctly, you can see bellow, but I think that there is a solution to my problem.

```
<Image
   height="600"
   width="800"
   src={
     'https://myImageURL.png'
   }
   alt="my image"
/>
```

Some questions:

- If I convert all images to .webp images is be showned faster?
- Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I've been having trouble with the same issue, mostly in Slider components. Basically, because the image is off-screen until the Slider moves it into view, there is a delay and it doesn't show for a short time, which looks nasty.

**Solution:**
Add the `sharp` package.
The problem comes from the default image processor that NextJS uses. I don't know if this is good for OP, but in my case, I hadn't fully read the docs. There is a tip that states:

> The next/image component's default loader uses the 'squoosh' library for image resizing and optimization. This library is quick to install and suitable for a dev server environment. **For a production environment, it is strongly recommended that you install the optional sharp library by running**

`yarn add sharp`

> in your project directory. If sharp is already installed but can't be resolved you can manually pass the path to it via the NEXT_SHARP_PATH environment variable e.g. NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/tmp/node_modules/sharp

After adding `sharp`, my images were processed much faster and there is no noticeable delay anymore. I would try adding this before adding `priority={true}` to every image, as that will impact the site performance.

Comment: Hi James, did you mean that you added `sharp` to your application bundle or, ran `yarn add sharp` as a part of the deploy command?

Comment: Hey Bishal, I ran ```yarn add sharp``` to add ```sharp``` to my project bundle and it sped up the images a lot for me.

Comment: Wow, that significantly improved the performance! Thank you James!

Comment: Big up man! Neat trick!

Comment: Hey James, I tried adding the `NEXT_SHARP_PATH` with both`/tmp/node_modules/sharp` and `/node_modules/sharp` in the environment variables on Netlify but it still doesn't resolve the issue. Any clues on how to resolve that? :')

Comment: I'm not familiar with hosting a Next.js app on Netlify, but as far as I know, Next.js is preconfigured to use `sharp` when it is installed in the project dependencies; that means you should only need to install `sharp`. [Here is a note](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#nodejs-server) in the hosting section of the docs that simply recommends to install `sharp`, and [here is the error message](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production) when you don't use `sharp` in production, along with solutions on how to install. Good luck!

Comment: note for anyone new that sharp is installed by default when hosting the app on vercel. bottom of the page at https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production. your best friend is the sizes property on next/image, and if not, check out all of the other props available that could potentially help you https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image.

Answer (score 31):

The problem is that the default behavior of the Image Component is [lazy loading](https://imagekit.io/blog/lazy-loading-images-complete-guide/#what-is-image-lazy-loading). You can change this behavior to [eager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading) by either adding the `loading` prop like this: `loading="eager"` or by adding `priority={true}`.

The [recommended way](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loading) is using `priority`.

About the image format. [Webp is smaller than png](https://www.shareus.com/windows/image-formats-comparison-webp-vs-jpg-vs-png.html), so it will load faster.

Comment: I think they've gone backward in some sections and specially performance.

Comment: That isn't the problem. The problem is how long it takes Next to serve the image on demand. They would have been much better off offering a static generation option for each defined image/screen size at build time and referencing the static file. Then just serve with NGINX - no need for Node.

Comment: doesn't `next/image` automatically load the image in [acceptable format](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#acceptable-formats) and optimize the load?

Answer (score 4):

1. upgrade your `next` higher than `11.0.2-canary.20`
2. `yarn add sharp`
3. beer

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23637#issuecomment-885631610

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11-1#image-optimization