# Image loading time (Next.js)

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I currently have a problem with the loading time of images using the builtin provided in Next js. I tried different options even when running it in production, the image loading time remains long (several seconds). Does anyone among you encounter this problem.

I am well aware that the first loading of the image can be long since there is a processing and caching on it. However this problem can appear even when the image is already cached.

```html
<Image
  className="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full"
  src="/imgs/myimage.jpg"
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="cover"
  alt=""
/>
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637391/next-images-components-are-too-slow-to-appear

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had already tried it. Even if I put my image as it is in high definition it is much faster. But the purpose of this builtin is normally to optimize the size, the compression of the image. Thank you