# Nextjs - very slow img loading

Tags: image, next.js, loading, lazy-evaluation

I use nextjs, i have small webp img, loading is from _next/ cache and it is too much slow, what i do bad?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anxeK.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next/Image's components are too slow to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637391/next-images-components-are-too-slow-to-appear)

Comment: First Next/image component loading="lazy" on default, secondly I think your image size isn't small