# Next.js: how to apply sharp lib in Next.js

Tags: image, next.js, sharp

`next/image` changes too slow, so I see the old images and then new images appear. For this issue, I have referred below:

[Next/Image's components are too slow to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637391/next-images-components-are-too-slow-to-appear)

> Install sharp by running `yarn add sharp` in your project directory and then reboot the server by running `next start` again

All of them say I should use `sharp`.

So I have added `sharp`. My question is should I just install `sharp` and `restart server`? Do I not need to import `sharp` and do some code?

I actually tried this way below:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';

const sharp = require('sharp');

const CustomImage = ({ src, href}) => {

  const rotateImage = () => {
    sharp(src)
  }
  
useEffect(() => {
  rotateImage()
}, [])

  return (
    <Link href={href} passHref>
        <span >
          <Image src={rotateImage}/>
        </span>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default CustomImage;
```

But it gives me this error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

How do I apply `sharp` in Next.js?

Comment: You simply install `sharp`, Next.js will use it in production mode if installed. No need to import it anywhere in your codebase.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to follow these two steps.

```
npm install sharp 

NEXT_SHARP_PATH: "/tmp/node_modules/sharp"
```

Worked pretty well for me.

Comment: Where are we meant to put the variable, `NEXT_SHARP_PATH`?

Comment: It's an environmental variable.  You can use a library like `dotenv` to keep it in a file,or you can just add it before the `next` command (eg. in your `package.json` script) ... for instance: `"start": "NEXT_SHARP_PATH=\"YOUR_PATH_TO_SHARP\" next start"`.

Comment: I tried it, but still im getting - Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

 What could be the reason?

Comment: This is fab, thanks so much, works like a treat!