# Getting 503 error on some image using next/image and aws s3 with hostend on amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, next-images

I am facing one problem when I am host my project to `aws amplify`. I successfully build a demo ecommerce project. I deploy this `next js` project to `aws amplify`. I use `next/image` component on my project. When I enter my site, I can see some images(Not all image) are not loaded properly. They show `alt` text instead. You can see this `gif` for understanding.

-https://media.giphy.com/media/bOekkFQdH2OVcoumwj/giphy.gif

You can see live url also- https://www.nekmart.com/

Please see the `gif` for understanding actual problem.

Here I host my image to `aws S3`. I use `cloudfront` also. For debugging my problem. I also deploy my project to `vercel` and `netlify`. From `vercel` and `netlify` I am not getting any kind image not loading issue.Here is those links-

Vercel link- https://nekmart-k71c.vercel.app/
Netlify link- https://remarkable-licorice-795c08.netlify.app/

But I have to use `aws`. Now How can I debug my problem? I can't understand actually where is the problem occured-

1. `next/image` component problem- I use it in this way- `<Image src={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGE_PATH + brand.image} width={25} height={25} alt={brand.name} />`
2. Need to setting up `aws amplify` properly?
3. Need to setting up `aws s3` properly?
4. Need to setting up `next config` for image component.

I am confused, Which one? Please help me to debugging this problem.

Comment: I've checked out the website and it turns out that some of your images are loading extremely slowly. (Upwards of 14s) That said, I don't think it is an issue cloudfront, or even amplify. Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637391/next-images-components-are-too-slow-to-appear

Comment: Your suggested answer show me two things. 1. Have to use `sharp` 2. Have to set `priority={true}` in every component. I try it. But issue still occurred. I have another questions- why in  vercel and netlify issue not occurring.