# How to speed up on-demand image optimization with next/image (next start)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js

When my Server gets setted up again (new `next-build and pm2 restart`) on Deploy. The Initial Load of Images takes way to long, like 30 - 50 seconds, I guess thats because `NextJS` does image optimization on-demand and not on build time to prevent huge build times when there are like several hundred images.

But it can't be that I have to visit my Sites on every device width after each deploy to get image optimization and better loading results for my users?

What are your advices to that? Do you scale down all your Images with 3rd Party tools and then again on-demand with `next/image`?
or do you ignore `next/image` directly? Or is there something i am missing right now?

I am using the `fill` property with the sizes pattern `(max-width: XX) XXvw, XXvw)`
and my Application is running with `next start` on my own hosted server, I do not use `next export` to generate a static site.

Till now I tried several things with `next/image` to shrink down my Image sizes.
using `fill` and `sizes` as mentioned, but the problem stays the same, on-demand image providing is in the worst case 50 seconds. And I guess thats because the User is requesting an certain image -> nextJS does optimize it -> returns it back to user. WHEN the first page load is executed, every other user benefits from it, because nextJS already have those compressed images.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637391/next-images-components-are-too-slow-to-appear?

Comment: @James wow that does improve on-demand by quite ALOT, i have missed that completly thought sharp is just for `next export` usage. Thanks, i will dig more into it to solve my now way smaller problem.